# ¿cómo registrar multiples tablas en una bd usando migration en laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

He estado adentrándome usando Laravel aun soy nuevo usando migraciones.
Lo que pretendo hacer es ¿cómo realizar el registro de varias tablas en la base de datos?

Por ejemplo:

Tengo la tabla login
`login[idusuario,nombre, contraseña]`

Tengo la tabla empleado 
`[idEmpleado, nombre, apPaterno, idusuario]`

lo que no entiendo es como realizar el registro de estas dos ya que la tabla empleado requiere llave foránea de login.
En mi controlador registrar tengo esto:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  Login::create($request->all());
}
```

Con esto hago que se registren primero los datos del login para después pasar la llave primaria como foránea en la tabla empleados, de aquí ya no se como seguir. Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estas confundido con lo que se refiere a las migraciones, pero con el problema vas bien, al crear a tu usuario solo tienes que almacenarlo en una variable

```
$usuario = Usuario::create();
```

de ahi solo crear tu arreglo para el empleado

```
[idUsuario => $usuario->id]
```

Comment: Gracias, olvide entrar y poner que ya habia resuelto el problema. Justamente fue lo que hice para realizar el registro de multiples tablas